# TSQL Pivot -- So Simple Yet Kicking My Butt

Tags: t-sql

I cannot for the life of me figure out why my pivot is not grouping the Elementary data onto one row...what am I doing wrong?  I have tried rewriting the query by not grouping the source data, grouping all the source data...is it because the pivot value is a string(varchar) value?

This is so embarrassing...

```
Create Table #temp 
(
endYear int, 
schoolLevelDescription varchar(25), 
staffCt int, 
staffADA decimal(5,1), 
trend varchar(10), 
srt int
)

Insert Into #temp Select 2018, 'Elementary', 2729, 93.2, 'red', 1
Insert Into #temp Select 2018, 'Combo', 169, 91.3, 'green', 4
Insert Into #temp Select 2018, 'High', 1467, 94.6, 'red', 3
Insert Into #temp Select 2019, 'Elementary', 61, 94.8, null, 1
Insert Into #temp Select 2018, 'Middle', 1027, 94.5, 'red', 2

Select  schoolLevelDescription,
        [2018]              y1, 
        IsNull([2019], '-') y2, 
        IsNull([2020], '-') y3, 
        IsNull([2021], '-') y4,
        trend 
From    (
        Select  endYear,
                schoolLevelDescription,  
                max(cast(staffCt as varchar(5)) + ' (' 
                    + cast(staffADA as varchar(5)) + '%)') val,
                trend,
                srt  
        From    #temp
        Where   endYear >= 2018 
        Group by endYear, schoolLevelDescription, trend, srt 
        ) src
Pivot   (
        max(val)
        For endYear in ([2018], [2019], [2020], [2021]) 
        ) pvt 
Order by srt 

Drop Table #temp
```

Comment: What's wrong? What did you expect and what did you get? Apart from the obvious syntax errors in the *INSERT* statement

Comment: As for aggregating *Elementary*, PIVOT has nothing to do with it. It deals with the *year* columns. It's GROUP BY that deals with `schoolLevelDescription` and `trend`. The `trend` values are *not* the same, one row has `red`, the other `null` so they belong to different groups

Comment: Thank You!!  That was actually another error that I just finished fixing -- there should be no 2019 data as of yet, which is why the trend field was null...but I wanted to ask the question because I was afraid something would be wrong once it did start to populate.  But now we are all good, again I appreciate you breaking it down for me.